# Size of unix directory with large number of files

Tags: unix, size

I have a unix directory containing around 100k small xml files and i want to calculate size of this directory.
I ran the command : `du -sh directory_name`

But command has been running for past 15 minutes. I believe the reason is large number of small files.
Is there any faster way to calculate the size in this scenario?

Comment: Please check this [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/950737/faster-du-stat-alternative-for-directories) question or this [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/529338/du-command-takes-way-too-long-to-run) question. You might also request the moderators to migrate this one to Serverfault/Superuser as this question will have better visibility there.

Comment: assuming that your hardware is post ~2008 and in good condition, are you sure there are not subdirs under `dir_name` that could be adding to the load on `du`? Or as you are tagged `unix` if you are in a corporate env. with a SAN that  you are scanning, this points to problems there (I've had this sort of thing happen in prev jobs). So I think your `du` cmd is probably doing the best you can hope for, and *may* be indicating a problem (as I would expect to scan 100K small files in a minute or so (maybe!) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `awk`, along the lines of:

```
ls -l | awk '{sum+=$5} END {print sum}'
```

Of course "ls -l" shows the "file size", not "disk space usage", but perhaps that's good enough for your purpose.

Comment: this will not help. ls -l itself will take ages.